# How can I get last record from a table?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with thousands of records, Now the problem is I want to get last record from the table. I don't know how to get, Can you please help us

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's better to have some field e.g. creation_date and do the following

```
select * from mytable order by creation_date desc limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use ORDER BY in the select statement and order DESCENDING to put the results you want at the top of the select. Then use SELECT TOP 1.

EG:

SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Table ORDER BY Field DESC

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
ORDER BY
        sorting_field DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if the table is designed correctly, there should be some sort of identification field.  This should be an auto number unless your using some sort of guid.

you could use

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM table
```

that would give you the most recent record entered into the table chronologicaly.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY index_field DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will help you

20.8.10.3. How to Get the Unique ID for the Last Inserted Row
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html

Answer (score 0):

Yuu could do this if you can't order by

```
Declare @Total int
SET @Total = SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM TABLE
```

To get the total number of records
And then doing a

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE RowNumber = @Total
```

Answer (score 0):

Largely a duplicate of

[How do I fetch the last record in a MySQL database table using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3411092/how-do-i-fetch-the-last-record-in-a-mysql-database-table-using-php)

Alternatively if you mean how do I get the last record in the order that the records were created, add a field say with an (ref INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE KEY)