# How to get only last iteration value while fetching data from the database,I've tried Getting values as JSON format

Tags: php, mysqli

Here's what i tried.
I've Tried fetch the data from DB.It shows data from the start of the iteration to the End of iteration.I need only last iteration value.I'm a complete noob. A help would be appreciated

```
   <?php
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "";
        $dbname = "api_db";
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        $myarray=array();
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        } 
        $sql = "SELECT id, name, description FROM products";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
                $myarray[]= $row; 


                // echo "<pre>";
                // print_r($myarray);

                echo "<pre>";echo json_encode($myarray);
                // echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["name"]. " - Description :" . $row["description"]. "<br>";
            }
        } else {
            echo "0 results";
        }
        $conn->close();

        ?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I fetch the last record in a MySQL database table using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3411092/how-do-i-fetch-the-last-record-in-a-mysql-database-table-using-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got your point that what you want-

***You need to get all record in one variable.Which you can encode at last***

For that do like below:-

1.Initialize array outside of the loop

2.Assign each record to the array inside the loop

3.Encode array outside the loop

Do like below:-

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "api_db";
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    $myarray=array();
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
    $sql = "SELECT id, name, description FROM products";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $myarray = []; //Initialize array outside of the loop
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
            $myarray[] = $row; //Assign each record to the array inside the loop
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
    $conn->close();
    echo json_encode($myarray);//Encode array outside the loop
?>
```

Comment: @SubashKumarKR  glad to help you :):)

Answer (score 1):

Change your SQL query to

```
SELECT id, name, description FROM products order by id desc limit 1
```

That will work for you.

Comment: i guess i confused you guys with my question.By adding this code i got only the last value of the DB.My default code Iterates every data from the DB.but It iterates The value one by one and the last iteration value has all the data. That's what i need Exactly!

Answer (score 0):

While it looks like a duplicate to me, I would suggest the following, **assuming that you are not intending to sort the dataset from the DBMS.**

Use [`mysqli_data_seek ( mysqli_result $result , int $offset )`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.data-seek.php) to move cursor that traverses the dataset. So for your case it would be

```
$nor = mysqli_num_rows($result); //Number of rows
mysqli_data_seek($resutl, ($nor - 1)); //Indices are based on 0
```

Basically `$nor` contains the total number of records. So the index of the last ever record would be `$nor-1`.

**Of course** if you are sorting the dataset in your query using `ORDER BY`, then the best way to do this is appending `ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1`.